# How to close NUnit through a batch file after the tests are run?

Tags: batch-file, nunit

So I have tests A, B, C 
I wish to run them through chrome and firefox. 
I use NUinit 2.6, selenium and c#

I have a bat file that first overwrites a config json with the specified browser for the selenium test project. Then runs nunit for that selenium project(has the A B C tests)

So its like

1)Change to Chrome then run nunit for A B C

2)Change to Firefox them run nunit for A B C

But my problem is in order to run 2, I have to manually close the test for 1

Is there a way to make 1 autoclose after its done running so 2 can start?

Thank you

Bat:

```
echo chrome | mySeleniumProject.exe
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 >NUL
start /w nunit-x86.exe mySeleniumProject.exe /run 
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 >NUL
echo firefox | mySeleniumProject.exe
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 >NUL
start /w nunit-x86.exe mySeleniumProject.exe /run
```

**Solved Differently:**

I decided to use nunits textfixture to pass in browser parameters in the selenium project, its much cleaner and better then using a bat file

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testFixture&r=2.5.9

Answer (score 0):

Make a taskkil at the end of test 1

```
taskkill /F /im chrome.exe
```

Comment: It kills chrome when I manually close the nunit test. I added the bat code that I use. I wish for the nunit-x86.exe to close by it self when the tests are done.

Comment: I don't now what your test does and how long it takes. But the only way to stop a process is with taskkill.